# Close intervals line in lyx

Tags: lyx

How can I make close intervals like the following in Lyx?

[image: interval lines]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In which context do you want to use these intervals? In running text or in a drawing? Edit you question and add a complete code sample that shows your situation.

Comment: Thanks! I added an example. I want it to be like a drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lyx allow you to use the `pmboxdraw` symbols in both text a math mode. Menu  <kbd>Insert</kbd> > <kbd>Special Characters</kbd> > <kbd>Symbols</kbd>. Then is only play with the math panels to use these symbols in `\oversert` or `\underset` or `\stackrel` and the like ...

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw, amsmath}
\def\raya{\textSFx\textSFx\textSFx\textSFx\textSFx\textSFx}
\parindent0pt\parskip1em    
\begin{document}
{\Huge text text text text text te}\par
\[\underset{\mbox{\textSFviii\raya\textSFix}}{2}\qquad\qquad
\underset{\mbox{\textSFviii\raya\textSFix}}{3}\qquad\qquad
\underset{\mbox{\textSFviii\raya\textSFix}}{4}\hfill\]\par
\(\underset{\mbox{\textSFviii\raya\raya\textSFix}}{1}\)\par
\[\underset{\mbox{\textSFviii\raya\raya\textSFix}}{5}\]\par
{\Huge text text text text text te}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank  you very much, exactly what I wanted